# Network Load Balancer Listening on Multiple Ports with Multiple Targets

Tags: amazon-web-services, load-balancing, amazon-elb

I have a use case where I need to set up an AWS Network Load Balancer listening on approximately 20,000 different high ports (30000+). The NLB needs to sit in front of a set of target nodes (EC2 instances) and route traffic from the port the NLB is listening on to the same port on one of the EC2 instances (all EC2 instances will be listening on all of the ports, so round-robining between the EC2 instances is totally fine). E.g., `request->NLB:32355->{one of any instance}:32355`.

I see that I can create TargetGroups which allow me to specify a set of instances and which ports they should be accessible by. However, it's unclear to me how I can associate a port on the NLB with a port on one of the instances. For example, I'd need port 32355 on the NLB to get sent to port 32355 on any of the EC2 instances, but only that port, and the same thing to happen for all other 19,999 ports I'm listening on.

Further context: this is a Kubernetes cluster with a bunch of Nodes behind the NLB that have NodePorts exposed. I need to reach those NodePorts through the NLB. Before the suggestions about different ways to handle this on k8s come in: trust me, we've thought this through and the global LB->node port option is our best bet here.

Bonus question: the number of Nodes behind the NLB is elastic, could scale up or down at any time. Is there a dynamic way, via tags or something, to ensure that the TargetGroups contains all of the Nodes that I need?

Answer (score 0):

You could use `type: LoadBalancer` for this on your Kubernetes Service.

```
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: service
  namespace: default
labels:
  app: service
spec:
  selector:
    app: app
  ports:
  - protocol: TCP
    port: 32355
    name: port
    targetPort: 32355
  type: LoadBalancer
```

This will automatically create and link your loadbalancer with the right port on the node and traffic will be routed from that port to the service and thus your application. You will have to do this for each port unfortunately. There is an issue open on GitHub to support dynamic port ranges:

https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/23864

Comment: Unfortunately this will create a load balancer per NodePort, whereas I'm looking to create a global load balancer that routes to all ports on all nodes.

Comment: you can just add ports in that service, these will all go on the same loadbalancer.